# Converting XML tags to uppercase using a javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to convert XML tags to uppercase, while preserving the case of attributes and text. So for example

```
<Mytag Category="Parent">Value1</Mytag>
```

Becomes

```
<MYTAG Category="Parent">Value1</MYTAG>
```

I have a regex which matches the XML tags correctly, but the upperCase function does not seem to be working.

```
myXmlElement.replace(/<(\/)*([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)([^>]*)>/g,"<$1" + "$2".toUpperCase() + "$3>")
```

I've also tried using `String.prototype.toUpperCase.apply("$2")`, as well as passing a function as the replace argument

```
myXmlElement.replace(/<[\/]*([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)[^>]*>/g,
                    function($1,$2,$3){return <$1 + $2.toUpperCase() + $3>})
```

But this doesn't work, as $1,$2,$3 appear to refer to the entire matching elements ($1 = , $2 = )

I'm sure there is something trivial I am overlooking here, can anybody help out?

Comment: That was a typo there, thanks for noticing. The params still don't have the correct value when I do it like that however.

Comment: Updated my comment to a full answer, hope that helps ;)

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse markup, it will fail. e.g. it can't distinguish CDATA that may contain matching patterns that aren't markup (such as script element content: `if(a<f)`.

Comment: I'm using this to parse some XML which I know won't contain anything apart from Elements, their attributes, and text content, so I don't think this would be an issue. Out of interest, if I was trying to parse some more generic XML, what alternative would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the characters before and after your tag name, the need to be put into matching braces within the pattern:

```
var pattern = /<([\/]*)([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)([^>]*)>/g 
var newTag = myElement.replace(pattern, function(full, before, tag, after) { 
  return "<" before + tag.toUpperCase() + after + ">"
})
```

The replacement function will take the `full` matching expression as first argument. That's why you simply may ignore it.
After that any matching brace of your pattern will be passed as a parameter.

Comment: That worked great, thanks. Matches being passed as params in order after the first was the missing piece :)